# Using Notepad++ Regex to find matches

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am trying to find matches with pattern:

```
GiM 00 (1234/5678 DF) (90,00%
```

The matches need to fulfil some conditions

1. The "00" needs to be higher than 20
2. The percentage needs to be 90,00% or higher

One note, the "1234/5678" can be from a two digit number up to a four digit number.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: 20 should not be matched, only 21..99 should be matched, right?

Answer (score 2):

If by the first point you mean to match 20..99, here's the regex:

```
GiM [2-9]\d \(\d{2,4}\/\d{2,4} DF\) \(((100,00)|(9\d,\d\d))%
```

Answer (score 1):

> The "00" needs to be higher than 20

Use `(2[1-9]|[3-9]\d)` to match two-digit numbers strictly above 20

> The percentage needs to be 90,00% or higher

Use `9\d,\d\d%` to match percentages greater than or equal to 90,00%

> the "1234/5678" can be from a two digit number up to a four digit number

Use `\d{2,4}` to match two-digit numbers to four-digit numbers. This will match numbers with leading zeros: for example `0003` would be matched as a four-digit number.

[Demo.](https://regex101.com/r/uX9iF9/1)

Comment: Thanks for your answer @dasblinkenlight . Tried to put them all together but it seams i can't make it to work. My regex are really bad i guess.

Comment: @Thanos Try [regex101](http://www.regex101.com) site, it gives nice visual feedback.

Comment: I've noticed that using 9\d,\d\d% finds the right matches but when adding the (9\d,\d\d% it finds nothing.

Comment: Most likely issue is with metacharacters (parentheses, dots, etc.) because you need to escape them. For example, `(9\d,\d\d%` needs to be `\(9\d,\d\d%` with a backslash.

Comment: @Thanos So you do need 21-99, not 20-99?